# Errors when using bclogo package

Tags: pstricks, bclogo

I'm trying to use `bclogo` package, but with a simple example like this I obtain series of errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bclogo}

\begin{document}


\begin{bclogo}{test}
hello world
\end{bclogo} 

\end{document}
```

**Error message if compiled with XeLaTeX**

> ! Package xkeyval Error: 'blur' undefined in families
>   ,pstricks,pst-grad,pst-node,pst-coil'.

**Error message if compiled with PDFLaTeX**

In addition to last error I have this one

> Undefined control sequence.  \c@lor@to@ps

Comment: That is  a bug in `bclogo`. You should report it to the author. With `xelatex` it should work without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pstricks` usage with `bclogo` needs either to load `\usepackage{pst-blur}` manually or `\usepackage[blur]{bclogo}`, which is easier and shorter, of course.

The manual (written in French however) states this on page 14, section 7.2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage[pstricks]{bclogo}% Or \usepackage[blur]{bclogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}{hello world}
  And now for something completely different
\end{bclogo} 
\end{document}
```

If the `tikz` option is used, the `blur` is not needed, since `bclogo` uses `TikZ` then. (This has been answered by gernot, but he deleted his answer unfortunately)

[image]

The special solution for bernard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[blur]{bclogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}{How to recognize trees from quite a distance away}
  Number 3: The Larch. 
\end{bclogo} 

\begin{bclogo}{}
  And now for something completely different
\end{bclogo} 



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ‘The larch’ would have been more suitable than ‘Hello world’, given the context ;o)

Comment: @Bernar: Le Larch ;-)

Comment: Just as  with Pepe le Pew?

Comment: @Bernard: A version for MP ;-)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it. What's MP? (I don't speak Acronym very fluently…)

Comment: @Bernard: Monty Python ...

Comment: So definitely not Member of Parliament…

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `blur` with `psset`. Otherwise it makes no sense to use the optional argument `blur` for the package `bclogo`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[blur]{bclogo}
\begin{document}

\psset{blur,shadow}
\begin{bclogo}{test}
        hello world
\end{bclogo} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it shouldn't throw an error when *not* using option blur and not using `pstricks`.